# Linux Mint Tkinter transparent window

Tags: linux, tkinter, window, transparent

I am trying to have a transparent background using Tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.attributes('-alpha', 0.1)
# root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.1) 
# root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")
# root.attributes("-fullscreen",True)
root.mainloop()
```

This code works fine in Windows, but not using Linux Mint Maya. Commented out are other options I have tried. Any suggestions what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you set the attribute, the window is not yet in a start where that works. To wait for that, add `root.wait_visibility(root)`:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.wait_visibility(root)
root.attributes('-alpha', 0.6)
root.mainloop()
```

(Confusingly, it can also work as a side effect of something else, like setting the window state, even to the same state it has.)

Answer (score 0):

Just setting `root.attributes('-alpha', 0.1)` does nothing for me as well in Linux, even after withdrawing/restoring the window. However, for a reason unknown to me, if you change the type of `root` first (even setting it to 'normal'), then the window becomes transparent:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.attributes('-type', 'normal')
root.attributes('-alpha', 0.1)
root.mainloop()
```

'-type' is a X11 only attribute.

As for your other attempts, `attributes` and `wm_attributes` are the same function so it is logical that your attempt with `root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.1)` did not work either.
Moreover, according to tcl/tk [documentation](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9457) '-transparentcolor' is a Windows only attribute, so it does not work in Linux.

Comment: I think it works as a side effect. What you actually need is `root.wait_visibility(root)` - so you need to have the window in a certain state, and the command has the side effect of causing this state.